# wordpress - get post that is assigned to the template

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the post that is assigned to this template and display the content, 
currently, I can only display the post content if I put the post id manually. I only want to display the content if the post is assigned to this template and display the content inside woocommerce page

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Sign up Page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

echo 'this is the signup page';


$post   = get_post(2);
$output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

You could try to use [get_page_template_slug()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/) function to check, if the current page uses specific template, something like:

```
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  $current_template = get_page_template_slug( get_the_ID() );

  if ($current_template == 'signup.php' )  {
      the_content();
  }

  endwhile;
```

Comment: yes, I am well aware of that,  this will not work for what I'm trying to do.  the post is being displayed inside woocommerce page

Comment: Updated the answer.